# Sort function from standard library gives an error using an iterator

Tags: c++, sorting, c++17

I am relatively new to C++ language and trying to implement sort function from algorithm library defined in standard namespace and use std::sort directly.
The common structure to sort a vector using sort is given using iterator and comparison function.

Consider vector `v as {4,3,5,9}` and after sorting it will look like `{9,5,4,3}.`
For an instance

```
 std::sort(v.begin(),v.end(),a>b)
```

So, I wanted to use this method to sort an list of nodes based on heuristic value for my A* search algorithm.Heuristic is basically addition of 2 attributes of Node object and I the sorting operation has to be done vector of this nodes and I want to use

```
open_list.begin() and open_list.end() as my iterators
```

to use my compare function as a third argument for std::sort() function here is actual implementation:

```
std::sort(open_list.begin(),open_list.end(),open_list.begin()->g_value + open_list.begin()->h_value > open_list.end()->g_value + open_list.end()->h_value );
```

Here, I basically am adding h and g values which are attributes of object Node and 
open_list is a vector of pointers to the nodes. I felt my implementation was right but it throws me a weird error which looks like this:

**/home/piyushkumar/CppND-Route-Planning-Project/src/route_planner.cpp:65:93: error: request for member ‘h_value’ in ‘*((RoutePlanner*)this)->RoutePlanner::open_list.std::vector::begin().__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >::operator->()’, which is of pointer type ‘RouteModel::Node*’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)
 std::sort(open_list.begin(),open_list.end(),open_list.begin()->g_value + open_list.begin()->h_value > open_list.end()->g_value + open_list.end()->h_value );**

Some clarification regarding the error:
`RouteModel` is an class and `Node` inherits from that class. Why this simple comparison function as a  3rd argument fails and says that you should use `->` which I have already used to retrieve values of g_value and h_value from Node object.

Any help and leads will be appreciated.

Comment: None of what you're doing is even potentially valid C++. Are you asking us to translate from whatever language that is into C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok let's sort things out one by one.

First about your error message. Your vector stores **pointers** and keep in mind that `a->b` is equivalent to `(*a).b`, so `open_list.begin()->h_value` equals to `open_list.front().h_value`, and a pointer clearly doesn't have member variable. To refer to the member variable, you need to write `(*open_list.begin())->h_value`. Furthermore, dereferencing `.end()` gives you undefined behaviour immediately. To access the last element of `std::vector`, use `.back()` instead of `*(you_vector.end())`. (Remember to check the vector is not empty beforehand! Otherwise you will step into undefined behaviour again :) )

Secondly your idea about how to use `std::sort` is wrong. To sort a range of elements by a "standard" you chose, the first two parameters of sort provide the information about the range, and the third parameter is your "standard", so it must be a "callable", and it takes two parameters and tell `std::sort` whether the first parameter should be sorted *before* the second. As a result, to sort `v` in descending order, you need to call `std::sort` in the following way:

`std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int a,int b)->bool{ return a > b;});`

Here, the third parameter is a lambda expression, if you don't know what the hell it is, google helps you. (FYI callable may not necessarily be a lambda expression, it may also be a function or a functor (a.k.a. function object) but I personally think lambda is the clearest one here.)

I will not give you the statement needed for sorting your `open_list`, you can use it to check whether you have figured out how the things work or not. Enjoy learning.

Comment: BTW I really think one should read (not browse) some books about C++ before diving into the playground, otherwise you got no clue about what are you doing.

Comment: Do you suggest any books for beginners?

Comment: @PiyushBhuva _C++ Primer_ . It helps you understand some very basic concepts of programming, good for someone who is completely new to programming or C++. Some of my friends argue that it is too detailed but I think it is not a issue for beginner.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so much not right here.

The third parameter to `std::sort` is a "callable" (think like a function pointer), which `std::sort` calls to compare two elements in the sequence. It needs to take two elements of the sequence (usually by `const &` and return a bool.

Your example `std::sort(v.begin(),v.end(),a>b)` will not work, because `a>b` is not callable.

Your "real" code suffers from the same problem.

```
std::sort(open_list.begin(),
          open_list.end(),
              open_list.begin()->g_value + open_list.begin()->h_value >
              open_list.end()->g_value +   open_list.end()->h_value );
```

That big expression is *not* callable, and *that*'s why the compiler is complaining.

Also, FWIW, `open_list.end()` is an iterator to the "one past the end" position in the sequence, and dereferencing it (as you do in `open_list.end()->g_value`) is undefined behavior, since there's no element there.

See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) for more info.